# Como enviar resultados de Quiz en Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, script

Necesito saber como luego de la ejecución de esta función Javascript, al dar el resultado en pantalla, me pueda enviar ese dato de resultado del quiz ya sea directamente a la base de datos o por url para así poder captarla con PHP, Ojo no se casi nada de Javascript por eso pido la ayuda...

Necesito es enviar el resultado final de alguna forma, para poder registrarlo en una base de datos.

Gracias... A continuación el código.

```js
!(function(a, b, c, d) {
  "use strict";
  (a.quiz = function(b, d) {
    var e = this;
    (e.$el = a(b)),
      e.$el.data("quiz", e),
      (e.options = a.extend(a.quiz.defaultOptions, d));
    var f = e.options.questions,
      g = f.length,
      h = e.options.startScreen,
      i = e.options.startButton,
      j = e.options.homeButton,
      k = e.options.resultsScreen,
      l = e.options.gameOverScreen,
      m = 1,
      n = 0,
      o = !1;
    (e.methods = {
      init: function() {
        e.methods.setup(),
          a(c).on("click", i, function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.start();
          }),
          a(c).on("click", j, function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.home();
          }),
          a(c).on("click", ".answers a", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.answerQuestion(this);
          }),
          a(c).on("click", "#quiz-next-btn", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.nextQuestion();
          }),
          a(c).on("click", "#quiz-finish-btn", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.finish();
          }),
          a(c).on("click", "#quiz-restart-btn, #quiz-retry-btn", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), e.methods.restart();
          });
      },
      setup: function() {
        var b = "";
        e.options.counter &&
          (b += '<div id="quiz-counter" style="color: #63c5bc"></div>'),
          (b += '<div id="questions">'),
          a.each(f, function(c, d) {
            (b +=
              '<div class="question-container" style="border-radius:10px;">'),
              (b += '<p class="question">' + d.q + "</p>"),
              (b += '<ul class="answers">'),
              a.each(d.options, function(a, c) {
                b +=
                  '<li><a href="#" data-index="' + a + '">' + c + "</a></li>";
              }),
              (b += "</ul>"),
              (b += "</div>");
          }),
          (b += "</div>"),
          0 === a(k).length &&
            ((b += '<div id="' + k.substr(1) + '">'),
            (b += '<p id="quiz-results"></p>'),
            (b += "</div>")),
          (b += '<div id="quiz-controls" style="border-radius:8px;">'),
          (b += '<p id="quiz-response"></p>'),
          (b += '<div id="quiz-buttons">'),
          (b +=
            '<a href="#" id="quiz-next-btn" style="border-radius:10px;">Siguiente</a>'),
          (b +=
            '<a href="#" id="quiz-finish-btn" style="border-radius:10px;">Finalizar</a>'),
          (b +=
            '<a href="back/con_eval.php?id=" id="quiz-restart-btna" style="border-radius:10px;">Cerrar</a>'),
          (b += "</div>"),
          (b += "</div>"),
          e.$el.append(b).addClass("quiz-container quiz-start-state"),
          a("#quiz-counter").hide(),
          a(".question-container").hide(),
          a(l).hide(),
          a(k).hide(),
          a("#quiz-controls").hide();
      },
      start: function() {
        e.$el.removeClass("quiz-start-state").addClass("quiz-questions-state"),
          a(h).hide(),
          a("#quiz-controls").hide(),
          a("#quiz-finish-btn").hide(),
          a("#quiz-restart-btna").hide(),
          a("#questions").show(),
          a("#quiz-counter").show(),
          a(".question-container:first-child")
            .show()
            .addClass("active-question"),
          e.methods.updateCounter();
      },
      answerQuestion: function(b) {
        if (!o) {
          o = !0;
          var c = a(b),
            d = "",
            g = c.data("index"),
            h = m - 1,
            i = f[h].correctIndex;
          if (g === i) c.addClass("correct"), (d = f[h].correctResponse), n++;
          else if (
            (c.addClass("incorrect"),
            (d = f[h].incorrectResponse),
            !e.options.allowIncorrect)
          )
            return void e.methods.gameOver(d);
          a("#quiz-response").html(d),
            a("#quiz-controls").fadeIn(),
            "function" == typeof e.options.answerCallback &&
              e.options.answerCallback(m, g === i);
        }
      },
      nextQuestion: function() {
        (o = !1),
          a(".active-question")
            .hide()
            .removeClass("active-question")
            .next(".question-container")
            .show()
            .addClass("active-question"),
          a("#quiz-controls").hide(),
          ++m === g &&
            (a("#quiz-next-btn").hide(), a("#quiz-finish-btn").show()),
          e.methods.updateCounter(),
          "function" == typeof e.options.nextCallback &&
            e.options.nextCallback();
      },
      gameOver: function(b) {
        if (0 === a(l).length) {
          var c = "";
          (c += '<div id="' + l.substr(1) + '">'),
            (c += '<p id="quiz-gameover-response"></p>'),
            (c += '<p><a href="#" id="quiz-retry-btn">Retry</a></p>'),
            (c += "</div>"),
            e.$el.append(c);
        }
        a("#quiz-gameover-response").html(b),
          a("#quiz-counter").hide(),
          a("#questions").hide(),
          a(l).show();
      },
      finish: function() {
        e.$el
          .removeClass("quiz-questions-state")
          .addClass("quiz-results-state"),
          a(".active-question")
            .hide()
            .removeClass("active-question"),
          a("#quiz-counter").hide(),
          a("#quiz-response").hide(),
          a("#quiz-finish-btn").hide(),
          a("#quiz-next-btn").hide(),
          a("#quiz-restart-btna").show(),
          a(k).show(),
          a("#quiz-results").html(
            " Obtuvistes " + n + " aciertos de " + g + " preguntas"
          ),
          "function" == typeof e.options.finishCallback &&
            e.options.finishCallback();
      },
      restart: function() {
        e.methods.reset(),
          e.$el.addClass("quiz-questions-state"),
          a("#questions").show(),
          a("#quiz-counter").show(),
          a(".question-container:first-child")
            .show()
            .addClass("active-question"),
          e.methods.updateCounter();
      },
      reset: function() {
        (o = !1),
          (m = 1),
          (n = 0),
          a(".answers a").removeClass("correct incorrect"),
          e.$el.removeClass().addClass("quiz-container"),
          a("#quiz-restart-btna").hide(),
          a(l).hide(),
          a(k).hide(),
          a("#quiz-controls").hide(),
          a("#quiz-response").show(),
          a("#quiz-next-btn").show(),
          a("#quiz-counter").hide(),
          a(".active-question")
            .hide()
            .removeClass("active-question");
      },
      home: function() {
        e.methods.reset(),
          e.$el.addClass("quiz-start-state"),
          a(h).show(),
          "function" == typeof e.options.homeCallback &&
            e.options.homeCallback();
      },
      updateCounter: function() {
        var b = e.options.counterFormat
          .replace("%current", m)
          .replace("%total", g);
        a("#quiz-counter").html(b);
      }
    }),
      e.methods.init();
  }),
    (a.quiz.defaultOptions = {
      allowIncorrect: !0,
      counter: !0,
      counterFormat: "%current/%total",
      startScreen: "#quiz-start-screen",
      startButton: "#quiz-start-btn",
      homeButton: "#quiz-home-btn",
      resultsScreen: "#quiz-results-screen",
      gameOverScreen: "#quiz-gameover-screen"
    }),
    (a.fn.quiz = function(b) {
      return this.each(function() {
        new a.quiz(this, b);
      });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

Responder el codigo que pusistes esta minificado por ende es bastante dificil entenderlo excepto si lo llevas a un formato legible. Usando este sitio online https://unminify.com/  pude entender lo que hacia ese script entonces lo que necesitas saber es que hay una funcion llamada **finish** mediante la cual puedes enviar la puntuación al acabarse el juego, de lo contrario si quieres hacerlo siempre pudes usar **updateCounter** que siempre es llamda cuando se responde una pregunta ya sea bien o mal entonces lo otro ke necesitas saber es que existen varias variables pero las ke te deben importar son **n**, **m** y **g**.

**n**: Es la cantidad de aciertos
**m**: La puntuacion actual
**g**: El total de puntuacion que deberias tener si acertaras todo

Entonces en alguna de esas 2 funciones podrias poner tu codigo para enviar esos datos a tu pagina de php, aqui te pongo un ejeplo, dependiendo de la libreria ke uses puedes hacerlo con ajax de una forma u otra

```
console.log('Aciertos: '+n+', puntos: '+m+', de un total de :'+g);
```

Algo asi con jquery

```
$.post('mi_pagina.php', {aciertos: n, actual: m, total: g}, function () {
   alert('Se ha enviado el codigo correctamente');
}).fail(function(){ console.log('error'); });
```

O con axios

```
axios.post('mi_pagina.php', {aciertos: n, actual: m, total: g}).then(function () {
   alert('Se ha enviado el codigo correctamente');
}).catch(function(){ console.log('error'); });

//Te debo con fetch ;P
```